# How to find count of objects within a list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an object:

```
Trip {
        private TripName tripName;
        private List<TripStops> tripStops;
}
```

Trip Stops contains

```
TripStops {
           private PackageObject packageObject;
           private PackageTask packageTask;
}
```

I'm trying to get the count of PackageObject inside trip stop using Java8.

Will I be able to do something like this? Or is there a better way

```
Integer packageCount = Trip.getTripStops.stream().filter(TripStops::getPackageObject).count
```

Answer (score 4):

To interpret the sentence *"I'm trying to get the count of PackageObject inside trip stop"* into code would be:

```
long count = Trip.getTripStops().stream().count();
```

or simply:

```
int count = Trip.getTripStops().size();
```

as each `TripStops` has *one* instance of `PackageObject`.

However, to get a count of the elements returned from `TripStops::getPackageObject` which pass a given criteria:

```
long count = Trip.getTripStops().stream()
                                .map(TripStops::getPackageObject)
                                .filter(criteria) // where criteria is the condition to be passed
                                .count();

// or merge map/filter into one with ---> .filter(t -> t.getPackageObject()...)
```

Comment: @Buccaneer you’re more than welcome. As a way of saying “thank you” you could upvote the answer and mark it as accepted. ;)